# How to implement UISearchController searchbar along with filter button in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I wanted to implement a search bar in ios swift using UISearchController. I need a button to open a filter screen along side the searchbar, something similar to screenshot attached. I am not able to adjust the width of searchbar in table header view.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create a container view that has both the search bar and your filter button, and set that as the table header view.

Comment: I have tried that, but as soon as I press the cancel button, the Searchbar goes back to the Tableheader view without the image